# Why am I getting all these errors in templates in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Here is the list of errors

Errors:

```
 ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
  F:\C Programs\TemplateClass.cpp|39|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'arraylist<x>::cap'| F:\C
  Programs\TemplateClass.cpp|11|note: declared here| F:\C
  Programs\TemplateClass.cpp||In instantiation of 'void arraylist<x>::fill() [with x = int]':| F:\C
  Programs\TemplateClass.cpp|65|required from here| F:\C
  Programs\TemplateClass.cpp|29|error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'int*')| c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\istream|168|note:
  candidate: 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]' <near match>| c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\istream|168|note:  
  conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:| F:\C
  Programs\TemplateClass.cpp|29|error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'bool&' to an rvalue of type 'bool'
```

```
//code

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>

template <class x>
class arraylist {
private:
    x* ptr;
    int cap, I;

public:
    arraylist(int cap)
    {
        ptr = new x[cap];
    }
    arraylist() //default constructor
    {
    }

    void fill()
    {
        cout << "Enter " << cap << " Elements :-\n";

        for (i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
            cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " Element : ";
            cin >> ptr + i;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void replace(int index, x value) //error message
    {
        *(ptr) + index = value;
    }

    void popdata(int index = cap - 1) //error message
    {
        delete (ptr + index);
    }

    void showdata(int index)
    {
        cout << "The data at index " << index << " is " << *(ptr + index);
    }

    void showlist()
    {

        for (i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
            cout << ptr + i << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    arraylist<int> a1;

    a1 = 10;
    a1.fill();
    a1.showlist();
    a1.replace(2, 87);
    a1.showlist();
    a1.popdata(9);
    a1.showlist();
    getch();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do a bit research on `conio.h`, in short, any code using it is horribly outdated by at least ten years. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. In any case, please extract and provide a well-formatted [mcve].

Comment: What do you think `a1 = 10;` is going to do?

Comment: Recommendation: Don't turn C++ error messages into quotes. Format them as code because often the whitespace has significance and C++'s heavy use of <> is mistaken for XML tags.

Comment: @Bob__ That is actually fine as it invokes the constructor. The compiler can find a constructor with one parameter and do the auto converion.

Answer (score 1):

First stop using this:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

The only reason you have it is so that you can use:

```
getch();
```

You can change that to ask for use input that will have the same affect:

```
#include <iostream>
...

std::cout << "Please hit return to exit application\n";
std::cin.get();
```

---

Please stop using this:

```
using namespace std;
```

Yes I know have to add `std::` in-front of a couple of things but in the long run this will make your life easier.

---

Bugs:

```
 // You have not specified the type of i
 for (i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
```

All variables in C++ need a type. Add a type like this:

```
 // Note: There are two places to fix this.
 for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
```

---

Your syntax fo accessing members of the array is slightly off:

```
 cin >> ptr + i;
 ...
 *(ptr) + index = value;
```

Change these to:

```
cin >> ptr[i];
...
ptr[index] = value;
```

---

```
void popdata(int index = cap - 1)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^ this part is not valid
                                 outside the class (where this is being called)
                                 you don't have accesses to the members.
```

To make it work get rid of that part for now.

```
void popdata(int index)
```

Comment: Rather than using `std::getline()` to wait for the user to exit the app, you could use `std::cin.get()` instead, which would be more inline with the OP's original use of `getch()`, eg: `std::cout << "Please hit any key to exit application\n"; std::cin.get();`